# How can I render Rails objects without redirecting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

apologies, as I'm relativity new to Rails development. I'm wanting to display Rails objects depending on a user's choice in a UI. Simplifying the question in terms of animals and zoos, :) ...

I have a Rails model for zoos that 'has many' animals. Parent-Child relationship.

In a given zoo 'show' page, I want the user to be able to select an associated animal from a dropdown box and have that animals's object details then displayed on the same page, i.e. without redirecting. Is there an EASY rails way to do this? Or do I have to go down the road of struggling to make Javascript talk to Rails variables?

Thanks in advance for your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: This is easily done in a rails application using the nice built in handling of AJAX. However, the explanation is rather extensive so I would recommend you read the docs for it. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html has a tutorial on how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a way but ajax to accomplish such task, Any way here's my sloution...

P.S Since you didn't provide any code, I had to make some assumptions...

- That a Zoo and an Animal both have only one attribute which is **Name**
- Animal's Info would be presented in an unorderd list
- You're using assets pipeline, coffescript and turbolinks 5

1st you should update your **zoos/show.html.erb** to have a the animals select menu, And the Animal's info list.

**app/views/zoos/show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @zoo.name %>
</p> 
<br>
<p>
  <strong>Animal:</strong>
  <%= select_tag "animals", options_from_collection_for_select(@zoo.animals, "id", "name"), id: 'select_animal', prompt: "Select Animal to view its info" %>
</p>

<div id="animalInfo">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Name: </strong><span id="animalName"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Created at: </strong><span id="animalCreated"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Updated at: </strong><span id="animalUpdated"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Second you should have in your **Animals** views a file called **show.json.jbuilder**, If you have it skip to the next step, else create it and put the following code...

```
json.partial! "animals/animal", animal: @animal
```

Third add the following code to your Zoo scripts, Look inside the code for explanation

**app/assets/javascripts/zoos.coffe**

```
ready = ->
  $('#animalInfo').hide() # hides the animal's info div
  $('#select_animal').change -> # listen to changes in the animals select menu
    if $(this).val() 
      animalId = $(this).val()
      output = undefined
      $.ajax #calls the animal object but its id
        url: '/animals/'+ animalId + '.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
        complete: (jqXHR, textStatus) ->
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) -> #return a json animal object
          # You can call any object attribute the same way with ruby
          # Like this: data.attribute
          # Edit this part to adapt with your code
          $('#animalName').text(data.name)
          $('#animalCreated').text(data.created_at)
          $('#animalUpdated').text(data.updated_at)
          $('#animalInfo').slideDown()
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    else
      $('#animalInfo').slideUp() # hides the animal's info div if no animal selected
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

I think you should tweak the code above to adapt with yours, But the concept would be the same, Hope It helps.